# In MLP, Why in the formula to calculate delta, the derivation of the cost function "(predicted - expected)" just as "(predicted - expected)" itself?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, derivative

I know that we have to perform the derivation of the terms, using the chain rule, to obtain the equations to calculate the gradients of the neurons.

**In this article:** https://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-backpropagation-algorithm-scratch-python/,
**The formula for calculating the gradient in the output layer was simply like this: `"(predicted - expected) * output_derivative"`**.  That is, it multiplies the error by the derivative of the output layer activation.  So, studying this, I think that in all cases to calculate the gradient I would just need to multiply the difference between the predicted and expected value (the error, i.e. the cost function) by the derivative of the layer's activation function, as described in this formula.

**But it seems that it won't always be this**, as I saw that in other articles and videos on YouTube, when they explain the derivation of the chain rule, the formula for calculating the gradients is different.  **For example, in a video, he taught that we need to calculate the derivative of the cost function, for example, he used the MSE cost function** (`which is "(predicted - expected) ^ 2"` ), and the derivative of this function was `"-2 * (predicted - expected)"`, **which was somewhat different from what I expected.**  I thought it would just be `"(predicted - expected) ^ 2 * output_derivative"` similar to another formula, but it was different, it ended up deriving the cost function, which was `"2 * (predicted - expected)"`, therefore **the complete formula to calculate the gradient was `"2 * (predicted - expected) * output_derivative"`, that is, it calculated the derivative of the cost function. That's why I was confused.**

**I had a question and wanted to ask:
Why was the derivation of the cost function "(predicted - expected)" in the article I mentioned just as "(predicted - expected)", that is, itself?  Why was the other explanation different?  Could someone please help me understand?**